# Update all odoo modules in a docker container

Tags: odoo

I am working on a Odoo Docker container. I tried to find the appropriate command to update all the modules through the command line there but in vain. What is the appropriate command to do so ? I've put docker restart container_name -u all but also in vain.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the `docker-compose up` command to start your servers, then you need to add the following line to your docker-compose.yml file under the odoo service:

```
command: odoo -u all -d odoo-prod
```

Where `odoo-prod` is the name of your database. This overwrites the default command (which is just `odoo` without update) and tells docker to update all modules when the container restarts.

Alternatively, you can also run a separate container that performs the updates:

```
docker run -v [your volumes] odoo:10.0 odoo -u all -d odoo-prod
```

This also overwrites the command from the dockerfile with the command stated here that includes the update.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` in your `Dockerfile` that runs `python odoo.py -u all`, the `-u all` option is for Odoo not `docker restart`

Comment: Hi danidee, i didn't get well your answer. Could you explain in detail what you mean by having an entry point in my docker file ?

Answer (score 1):

Open your container console

```
docker exec -it odoo bash
```

Update your module using other port

```
/usr/bin/odoo -p 8070 -d mydb -u mymodule
```

If the database it's on another container

```
/usr/bin/odoo -p 8070 --db_host=172.17.0.2 --db_user=odoo --db_password=odoo -d mydb -u mymodule
```