# How to update Odoo module via Docker CLI

Tags: docker, docker-compose, odoo, odoo-15

I learn to use Docker

I used to use Odoo in a local instance.
For my changes concerning the XML or the database structure I stopped the server and used `python3 ./odoo/odoo-bin -c myconf.conf -u custom_module`

I now use an Odoo app in a Docker container.

`docker-compose up --build` allows me to restart the server at each implementation, and I go to my Applications menu> custom_module> 'Update' button for module updates.

I think there are much better practices, but I can't find any tutorial or doc about **updating Odoo module via Docker CLI**. I am interested in any good practice concerning my case (Docker/App Odoo 15/ Psql 14)

My question is quite similar to this case

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263764/update-all-odoo-modules-in-a-docker-container

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the question you shared, there is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46442631/12371874) which seems quite the solution.
Just add a command with the `-u my_module` before running Odoo

For more specific help, you should share your compose file content.